# Wasabi API over HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: ubuntu, docker, server, intuit-wasabi

I am trying to serve Wasabi API over HTTPS. Currently, it is HTTP only.

I have a very basic setup ( as described here https://github.com/intuit/wasabi ) running on Ubuntu 16.04 on Google Cloud.

It is accessible via http://example.com:8080 and that seems to be the only port that's used for the API.

`$ docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                     NAMES
ad37f34cf204        wasabi-main         "entrypoint.sh wasabi"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8090->8090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8180->8180/tcp    wasabi-main
df6ac72359d7        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint.sh"   6 days ago          Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                                                    wasabi-mysql
4d7659ae5321        cassandra:2.1       "/docker-entrypoint.s"   6 days ago          Up 8 minutes        7000-7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp, 7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9160->9160/tcp   wasabi-cassandra
```

I would be happy with both solutions, running both HTTP and HTTPS or HTTPS only.

PS! example.com itself is available over HTTPS

Comment: @james-todd maybe you have an idea here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, the Jetty container (wasabi-main) only serves HTTP traffic, and is not set up to serve HTTPS. What we usually do to serve HTTPS is place an Apache/Nginx proxy in front that does SSL termination, and then forwards the non-ssl request to Jetty.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you please give me some further details, an example or a related tutorial, because I am a bit stuck here setting up the proxy. Thanks

Comment: Got it now. Thanks!